# How many requests will a Video chat application make to the QuickBlox broker

Tags: quickblox

I'm looking at the Quickblox demo for Video chat, and am interested in perhaps signing up, can someone provide some information on how much resources are needed to run an instance of the Video chat application, per conversation would be fine, may be able to calculate the total for the desired usage. As I understand it the service is a broker for the connection so in theory should be quite small? But would that mean with the Free for instance I would be limited to a single connection being limited to 20 connections per any 20 second period, so if I had a class of 30 I'd need to throttle 10 to have all connect to the chat?

http://quickblox.com/plans/

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @jurgemaister not sure where to post, this is where the contact form sends you.
http://quickblox.com/contact/

Is there somewhere else you would recommend to post this?

Comment: This sounds like a question for their help desk.